# Objects Teleport to 0, 0, 0 When I Press Play

Tags: unity-game-engine

This is bizarre and I've never seen it happen before, but as the title suggests, many of my assets randomly teleport to 0, 0, 0 when I press play.

I downloaded a pack of buildings from the Unity asset store. I placed them around how I wanted, but when I tried running the game, they all just teleported to the middle. It only does it with these specific buildings.

I tried placing some other objects, but they all work normally.

Is there some way I can lock them in place, or is there another fix for this?

Comment: It's actually encouraged to answer your own question. Answers in comments hold no value. Please post your own answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Those assets must have some code that do that behaviour, make sure about what components have those assets.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you're moving the objects the game is stopped and not paused or playing.
You can move objects whilst the game is being played but unless you move them when the game is stopped it will spawn them at the default position once u start the game again.
This can be done on the top middle of your play screen.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I just figured out the issue. I disabled the animation component, and now it works. Leaving this up in case anyone else has this problem